# Using net.DialTimeout with specific local port

Tags: go

I'm trying to use specific source IP port, but net.DialTimeout does not have laddr parameter

```
my_dial, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", addr, 3*time.Second)
conn := tls.Client(my_dial, tlsconf)
```

Then I checked the document, the only method that support `laddr` is:

```
func DialIP(network string, laddr, raddr *IPAddr) (*IPConn, error)
```

But it returns net.IPConn instead of net.Conn.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`Dial` and `DialTimeout` are just helpers around the [`net.Dialer`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dialer) type, which has all the available options documented.

You can set a local address and the timeout. The `Dialer` also has a [`DialContext`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dialer.DialContext) method to use a context directly rather than a timeout if desired.

```
d := net.Dialer{
    LocalAddr: lAddr,
    Timeout: timeout,
}
conn, err := d.Dial(network, address)
...
```